# PHP 5.3.8 fopen on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, fopen

I'm working with a project where the client is running WordPress on Windows 2003. They upgraded to PHP 5.3.8 and *most* things are working well. They aren't able to connect to outside services, though, such as the WordPress Plugin API.

They've setup error logging and here's an example of one of the errors, triggered by testing the PHP Streams transport via the Core Controls plugin in WordPress.

```
[06-Oct-2011 13:45:02] PHP Warning:  fopen(http://tools.dd32.id.au/wordpress/core-control.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato.
 in C:\..[path].. \wp-includes\class-http.php on line 876
```

In the .ini, allow_url_fopen is set to "On".

Any recommendations for what should be checked next?

**UPDATE**

It looks look the issue may be firewall related. When testing cURL via Core Control, I get the following error:

```
An Error has occured: couldn't connect to host
```

And when testing PHP fsockopen(), I get the following error:

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to tools.dd32.id.au:80 (Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato. ) in C:\Inetpub\www\profesionfarmacia.es\landing\beta\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 629
An Error has occured: 10060: Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato.
```

If it is a firewall issue, do you have any specific recommendations for what be done?

Comment: What does `Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato.` mean?

Comment: Looks like the server is unable to connect outside. Could be a  firewall issue - maybe this helps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778148(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a firewall issue as well.. Taking a look at that article. Any other ideas or suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: As for the message, its essentially a "time out". Here's Google's rough translation: "Connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or lack of response from the host connected."

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can access the web page from a different client running on the same machine (i.e. DNS lookup working, outgoing HTTP requests working).

Is safe_mode off?

While I'm not sure if it is applied to the stream wrappers, is open_basedir in effect? Does it include 'http://'?

C.

Comment: Ah, in other words, checking to see if I can visit the target of fopen from another client on the server. I'll test that. safe_mode is off. open_basedir is not in effect.